# Mongodb autostart with linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, startup

I have recently updated mongodb on my AWS linux server with

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

The result was that the mongod command would no longer successfully launch the mongodb server, because I would get an error saying the directory that it does not find the data directory /data/db/, even though in mongodb.conf if says:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
```

and in my init.d/mongod it points to that config file: `CONFIGFILE="/etc/mongod.conf"`

So I now have the following questions:

1. Why do I now have to manually start mongod with mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo. Starting it without the -dbpath option results it in ignoring that path that is stated in /etc/mongod.conf. Why?
2. What can I do to make sure that on a reboot it will look in the right data directory again, as it did before I did the update?
3. Should I have done something differently when updating instead of sudo yum install -y mongodb-org?

Comment: "yum install" installs new software, it doesn't update it. Can you do "yum list installed | grep mongo" to see if you have multiple versions installed?

Comment: Repository 'mongodb-org-3.0': Error parsing config: Error parsing "gpgcheck = '9'": invalid boolean value
mongodb-org.x86_64                 3.2.11-1.amzn1               mongodb-org-3.2
mongodb-org-mongos.x86_64          3.2.11-1.amzn1               mongodb-org-3.2
mongodb-org-server.x86_64          3.2.11-1.amzn1               mongodb-org-3.2
mongodb-org-shell.x86_64           3.2.11-1.amzn1               mongodb-org-3.2
mongodb-org-tools.x86_64           3.2.11-1.amzn1               mongodb-org-3.2

Comment: Why on earth are you using Amazon Linux?

Comment: It's free tier, but I don't think that's an issue

Comment: @Tim that's not entirely true. `yum install foo` will update foo if it's already installed an update is available.

Comment: Any suggestions what could be the cause?